# Indefinite integral of $\int\sqrt{x^2-1}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, radicals

How to calculate $\int\sqrt{{x^2}-1}dx$?

I tried to use 1st and 3rd Euler substitution and got the answer, but I suppose there's an trigonometrical replacing that gives the answer analytically.

Comment: By "faster," do you mean "analytically," as opposed to "numerically"?

Comment: analytically ofc.

Comment: what do you mean 'euler' substitution?

Comment: $x=\cosh(t)$ works pretty nice.

Comment: Hyperbolic substitution must work nice, we're integrating $x^2-y^2=1$.

Comment: Euler substitutions are useful in finding integrals of the likes of square root of quadratics. More [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution)

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1874124/evaluating-int-sqrtx2-3-dx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $x=\sec t$, then $dx=\sec t\tan t\, dt$ and
\begin{align}
\int\sqrt{x^2-1}\,dx&=\int\sqrt{\sec^2 t -1}\sec t\tan t\,dt\\
&=\int\sqrt{\tan^2 t}\sec t\tan t\,dt\\
&=\int\sec t\tan^2 t\,dt
\end{align}
Next, integration by parts can be applied:
\begin{align}
\int\sec t\tan^2 t\,dt&=\tan t\sec t-\int\sec^3 t\,dt\\
&=\tan t\sec t-\int(\tan^2 t+1)\sec t\,dt\\
&=\tan t\sec t-\int \sec t\tan^2 t\,dt -\int\sec t\, dt\\
2\int\sec t\tan^2 t\,dt&=\tan t\sec t-\ln |\sec t+\tan t|\\
\int\sec t\tan^2 t\,dt&=\frac{1}{2}\tan t\sec t-\frac{1}{2}\ln |\sec t+\tan t|+C
\end{align}
Then, since $\sec t=x$ we can put $\tan t=\sqrt{\sec^2 t-1}=\sqrt{x^2-1}$, hence
$$\boxed{\color{blue}{\int\sqrt{x^2-1}\,dx=\frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{x^2-1}-\frac{1}{2}\ln |x+\sqrt{x^2-1}|+C}}$$

Comment: How are you going from $\sqrt{\tan^2 t}$ to $\tan t$, given that $t=\sec^{-1} x$, and the range of $\sec^{-1} x$ is typically $[0, \pi]$, so that $\tan t$ could be negative? Shouldn't it be $\sqrt{\tan^2 t}=|\tan t|$?

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, take $x=\cosh{t}$. Then $dx=\sinh{t} \, dt$ and
$$ \int \sqrt{x^2-1} \, dx = \int \sqrt{\cosh^2{t}-1} \sinh{t} \, dt = \int \sinh^2{t} \, dt. $$
Now,
$$ \cosh{2t} = \cosh^{2}{t}+\sinh^2{t} = 1+2\sinh^2{t}, $$
so this is
$$ \frac{1}{2}\int (\cosh{2t}-1) \, dt = \frac{1}{4}\sinh{2t}-\frac{t}{2}+C = \frac{1}{2}(\cosh{t}\sqrt{\cosh^2{t}-1}-t)+C = \frac{1}{2}(x\sqrt{x^2-1}-\arg\cosh{x})+C $$

Answer (score 1):

**Integration without substitution**

Notice, there is another method without any substitution, using integration by parts, let
$$I=\int\sqrt{x^2-1}\ dx$$$$=\int \sqrt{x^2-1}\cdot 1dx$$
$$I=\sqrt{x^2-1}\int 1\ dx-\int \left(\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)\cdot \int1 dx\right)dx$$
$$I=\sqrt{x^2-1}(x)-\int \frac{x(2x)}{2\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx$$
$$I=x\sqrt{x^2-1}-\int \frac{(x^2-1)+1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx$$
$$I=x\sqrt{x^2-1}-\int\sqrt{x^2-1} dx+\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx$$

$$I=x\sqrt{x^2-1}-I+\ln|x+\sqrt{x^2-1}|+C$$
$$2I=x\sqrt{x^2-1}+\ln|x+\sqrt{x^2-1}|+C$$
$$I=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}\left(x\sqrt{x^2-1}+\ln|x+\sqrt{x^2-1}|\right)+C}$$

Comment: Though your answer is clean, OP specifically wanted a trigonometric substitution

Comment: The OP supposed that there is a trig substitution to do the job. But looking at the OP's  trials I would assume that he may be open to alternative ,methods as well, as we all should... So time for an upvote to compensate the downvote.