# Evaluating $\int \sqrt{x^2-3}\:dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, radicals

I need to solve:

$$\int \sqrt{x^2-3} \, dx.$$

So I use the substitution:

$$x=\frac{\sqrt 3}{\cos(t)}$$

$$dx= \frac{\sqrt 3 \sin(t) \, dt}{\cos^2(t)} $$

and I get

$$3\int \frac{\sqrt{\frac1 {\cos^2(t)}-1}\cdot\sin(t) \, dt}{\cos^2(t)}. $$

So I get

$$3\int \frac{\sin(t)\tan(x)\,dx}{\cos^2(x)},$$
that is $(\sin(t)\sin(t)/\cos(t))/\cos^2(t)$ and finally I have

$$3\int \frac{\sin^2(t)\,dt}{\cos^3(t)}$$

Substitute $\sin(t)=s$, so $\cos(t) \, dt=ds$. The integral becomes

$$3 \int \frac{s^2\,ds}{(1-s^2)^2};$$
$$dt= \frac{ds}{\cos t}$$

So problem is I don't know how do I get from this $\sqrt{(1/\cos^2(t))-1} = \tan(t);$

It was stupid question idk how I didn't saw that nvm, after that use partial integration $u=s$, $du=ds$, $v=1/(1-s^2)$ and i get $s/2(1-s^2)-1/2$ integral of $ds/(1-s^2)$
and the solution is $3/2(s/1-s^2-1/2\ln(1+s/1-s)$

Comment: This is an _integral_, not an integer.

Comment: It is a bit hard to read and understand the question!

Comment: $$\text{Integer}=0,1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,\ldots\\ \text{Integral}=\int$$

Comment: Please reedit.  This is unreadable.  What the heck is tgt?

Comment: I did not read anything but the last line, so this might not be helpful. $$\sqrt{\frac1{\cos^2 x}-1}=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos^2x}{\cos^2x}}$$ and here's where you remember what $1-\cos^2x$ is.

Comment: Wait... Do you wanna ask why $\sqrt{(1/\cos^2(t))-1} = \tan(t)$ or do you want to know how to continue with $3 \int \frac{s^2\,ds}{(1-s^2)^2}$?

Comment: I finished integral,i was stupid idk how i didn't saw that 1+cos^2(t)=sin^2(t) and when i put that back i get sin^2(t)/cos^2(t) and thats tg^2(t) bcs of sqrt its tg(t).Sry it was stupid question from me

Comment: Please, avoid SMS language! It makes everything harder to read.

Comment: Okey,sorry my english is not that great so i will try to write better.

Comment: @fleablood : I would take "tgt" to mean $\operatorname{tg}t$, i.e. what in recent decades is usually denoted (at least when writing in English) as $\tan t$.  A hundred years or more ago one sometimes saw $\operatorname{tg}t$ or $\operatorname{tang}t$ or other abbreviations in things written in English; one still sees them today in things written in some other languages. $\qquad$

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Closely related post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1445147/indefinite-integral-of-int-sqrtx2-1dx

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta = 1$$ so dividing both sides by $\cos^2 \theta$ gives $$1 + \tan^2 \theta = \frac{1}{\cos^2 \theta} \iff \frac{1}{\cos^2 \theta} - 1 = \tan^2 \theta$$

And so, taking the square root of both sides gives you what you want.

Comment: Since the main question appeared to be expressed as "So problem is I don't know how do I get from this $\sqrt{(1/\cos^2(t))-1} = \tan(t);$", this is the only really good answer so far. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. As you have suggested, the change of variable
$$
x=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\cos t},\quad dx=\frac{\sqrt{3}\sin t}{\cos^2 t}\:dt,
$$
gives
$$
\begin{align}
\int \sqrt{x^2-3}\:dx&=\sqrt{3}\int\sqrt{\frac3{\cos^2 t}-3}\:\cdot \frac{\sin t}{\cos^2 t}\:dt
\\\\&=3\int\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos^2 t}{\cos^2 t}}\:\cdot \frac{\sin t}{\cos^2 t}\:dt
\\\\&=3\int \frac{\sin^2 t}{\cos^3 t}\:dt
\\\\&=3\int \frac{\sin^2 t\: \cos t}{(1-\sin^2 t)^2}\:dt
\\\\&=3\int \frac{s^2}{(1-s^2)^2}\:ds
\end{align}
$$ can you take it from here?

Comment: I think at some point the OP arrived at your last line already.

Comment: @ArcticChar Yes, I've seen it. that's why I ask him if it is Ok.

Comment: That big sqrt how do i get a tan(t) of it   ,,,,,,1-cos^2t/cos^2t

Comment: @user5927353 Like this: $$\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos^2 t}{\cos^2 t}}=\sqrt{\frac{\sin^2 t}{\cos^2 t}} =\tan t$$ Is it Ok? we assume $\tan t\ge0$.

Comment: Idk how i didn't see this......,and how can i write like that with?

Comment: It sometimes happens :)

Comment: Can you tell me how can i write in that format where is everything alot easier to read?(math format)

Comment: more information can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Welcome to MSE btw. @user5927353

Comment: Is it possible to post question about eletrical engineering and hope to get answered?(about current and 
electrostatics),or this is only for math?

Comment: Did you try [physics SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/)? @user5927353

Comment: @user5927353 there is also http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ But check the help-center first to see what type of questions they accept and what type of recommendations they have for how to ask.

Answer (score 0):

$3\int \frac {\sin^2(t)}{\cos^3(t)} dt$

Rather than a substitution I suggest you do this.

$3\int \tan^2 t \sec t dt$

integration by parts:

$u = \tan t, dv = \sec t \tan t dt\\
du = sec^2 t dt, v = sec t$

$3\sec t \tan t - 3\int \sec^3t dt\\
3\sec t \tan t - 3\int (\tan^2 t - 1)\sec t dt\\
3\sec t \tan t + 3 \int \sec t dt - 3\int \tan^2 t \sec t dt\\
3\sec t \tan t + 3 \ln |\sec t + \tan t| - 3\int \tan^2 t \sec t dt$

And we have come full circle:

$3\int \tan^2 t \sec t dt = 3\sec t \tan t + 3 \ln |\sec t + \tan t| - 3\int \tan^2 t \sec t dt\\
3\int \tan^2 t \sec t dt = I\\
I = 3\sec t \tan t + 3 \ln |\sec t + \tan t| - I\\
2 I = 3\sec t \tan t + 3 \ln |\sec t + \tan t|\\
I = \frac 32 \sec t \tan t + \frac 32 \ln |\sec t + \tan t|+C$

Alternatively, If you want to stick with your initial approach.

$\int \frac {s^2}{(1-s^2)^2} ds$

Find a partial fraction decomposition:

$\frac {s^2}{(1-s^2)^2} = \frac A{1-s} +\frac B{1+s} + \frac C{(1-s)^2} + \frac D{(1-s)^2}$

And that will integrate to

$-A\ln (1-s) + B\ln(1+s) + C(1-s)^{-1} - D(1+s)^{-1} + c$ (sorry do double use the same letter)

Hopefully, the two answers are equivalent.

Comment: Can you tell me how can i write in that format where is everything alot easier to read?(math format) –

Answer (score 0):

First rescale

$$\int \sqrt{x^2-3} \, dx=3\int \sqrt{t^2-1} \, dt.$$

Then by parts,

$$\int \sqrt{t^2-1} \, dt=t\sqrt{t^2-1}-\int\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}dt=t\sqrt{t^2-1}-t-\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}.$$

In the last integral, you should recognize the derivative of $\text{arcosh }t$.

Comment: Well, if the question is "So problem is I don't know how do I get from this $\sqrt{(1/\cos^2(t))-1} = \tan(t);$", then I don't think this addresses it. $\qquad$