# Shell surface of hyperboloid

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, hyperbolic-functions

I need to calculate the shell surface of a hyperbola rotating around the $x$-axis and therefore generating a hyperboloid. To calculate the shell surface I should use the integral formula for the shell surface. The equation of the hyperbola is:
$$\frac{x^2}{9}-\frac{y^2}{16}=1.$$
The border values of the integral reach from $-5$ to $5.$

First of all I need to get y and the derivation of y. Accordiung to the hyperbola equation I mentioned above $y$ should be: $y=4\sqrt {(x^2/9)-1}$.

At this point I got a little bit stuck. I tried some things but none of them ended up in giving me the expected solution ($\approx 198$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It remains to apply the formula for the [surface of revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_revolution#Area_formula):
$$2\cdot 2\pi\int_3^5f(x)\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}\, dx=
16\pi\int_3^5\sqrt{\left(\frac{5x}{9}\right)^2-1}\,dx
$$
where $f(x)=4\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{9}-1}$ is the function that you have found.
In order to evaluate the integral, take a look at [Indefinite integral of $\int\sqrt{x^2-1}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1445147/indefinite-integral-of-int-sqrtx2-1dx?noredirect=1). You can check the final result at [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=16*Pi%20integral%20%28sqrt%28%285*x%2F9%29%5E2-1%29%20x%3D3..5).

Notice the interval of integration: by symmetry we consider $0\leq x\leq 5$ such that $\frac{x^2}{9}-1\geq 0$, i.e. $x\geq 3$ and we double the final result.

Comment: Thank you! I got the actual equation and messed up the integration interval, therfore my calculator always threw an error...

Comment: @VR46_Italia You are welcome. See also the link I gave you for the indefinite integral.

Comment: I will take a look at it, thanks for providing. Just one more question, how do I know thath I have to take 3 as the lower border for the integration interval?

Comment: See the domain of definition of $f$: the argument of the square root should be non-negative i.e. $ \frac{x^2}{9}-1\geq 0$

Comment: Ok and therfore I have to take the smallest number which makes the term under the square root positive, right?

Comment: @VR46_Italia Yes, exactly

Comment: Got it, thanks for your time and explanation!